# How To Change the Default Button Of Angular2CSV

Tags: angular, plugins, angular2-template

I am Using angular 4 and use Angular2CSV plugin to import data from angular page to #Microsoft Excel. All is done accurately. I want to change the name of button but i don't know how is it possible.Now default button name is Download but no html tag is available for this. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Create a separate component in your shared module and export it so other components that import the module can use it

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Angular2CsvComponent } from 'angular2-csv';

@Component({
selector: 'app-export-csv',
template: '<div (click)=\"onDownload()\"><ng-content></ng-content></div>',
styleUrls: ['./export-csv.component.scss']
})
export class ExportCSVComponent extends Angular2CsvComponent {}
```

Then in you the .html file you intend to export, use the below

```
<app-export-csv [data]="exportTxnData" filename="Transaction file" [options]="options">
        <button style="float: left" mat-mini-fab color="primary"><mat-icon>file_download</mat-icon></button>
   </app-export-csv>
```